# Inserting a row at a specified location in a 2D STL vector C++

Tags: c++, stl, insert

I have a 2-dimensional integer vector. I need to insert a new integer vector at a specified location in the 2D vector(say before the 6th row). I came up with something like this:

```
//2d vector
vector< vector<int> > layout(100,vector<int>(100,0));
//vector to be inserted
vector<int> dummy(10);
//iterator pointing to the position at which the new vector needs to be inserted
vector< vector<int> >::iterator it=layout.begin()+5;    //6th row
layout.insert(it,1,dummy);
```

I even tried:

```
it=layout.insert(it,dummy);
```

Neither seem to work. And the interesting part is that the syntax seems to be right because the compiler keeps giving me "Segmentation fault". I have checked the size of the 2-D vector and it is way more than 5(it is around 100).
How can I fix it?

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help here.

Comment: Your example code is indeed obviously incorrect (layout has size zero at the time of the insert).

Comment: My apologies. I wrote that in a hope to explain my situation better. Anyway I have checked  the vector. And at the time of insert it contains 100 vectors with 100 integer variables in each vector.

Comment: Then the segfault is not coming from inserting. We really need to see an example of your real code to help further. I suspect you're working on invalidated iterators and/or references, though.

Comment: I am sorry. I just realized the mistake I had committed. Working perfectly now. Thank you for your help.